# Error 141: libgazebo_ros_control can not be found in Gazebo 2.0.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When running my simulation using Gazebo 2.0.0, I get the following non-critical error:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:141] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so: 
libgazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't use the ROS control part of the simulation for now, so it doesn't matter too much. However, I thought I should mention it here. I think that the current `ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control` package might still be linked against Gazebo 1.9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4753/error-141:-libgazebo_ros_control-can-not-be-found-in-gazebo-2.0.0/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/519/rafberkvens/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-16**:
We are finishing the work on solving the problem with gazebo-2.0.0 and ROS. Hopefully there will be some news in few hours about how to properly install and run them together. I will update the answer as soon as the official instructions are released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The error was not in your part, it was due to an unstable state of the ROS and OSRF repository. Should be fixed now.

[Full instructions](http://gazebosim.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2013-October/000040.html) to install gazebo-1.9 or gazebo-2.0 (gazebo-current) were sent to the gazebo mailing list including how the integration with ROS is working.

**Update 22 Oct:** there is a new document about [Gazebo/ROS integration](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS) which should help to fix all aspects related to gazebo and ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/519/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-17**:
According to [those instructions](http://gazebosim.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2013-October/000040.html), Gazebo 1.9.2 would be installed when installing ROS. I purged all `gazebo`, `gazebo-current`, `ros-hydro-desktop-full`, `ros-hydro-gazebo-*` packages from my system and did a fresh `ros-hydro-desktop-full` install. It automatically selects `gazebo-current`. The `ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control` packages can still not be installed, because they look for `gazebo`.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-17**:
I see, you probably are running raring so it is pulling the OSRF dependencies for ros-hydro-gazebo-* (which have a greater version) which brings gazebo-current to you. I see several solutions here. Probably the easiest one is to remove OSRF repo from your apt sources unless you have a different reason to keep it. I will write some instructions to solve this problem.

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/519/rafberkvens/) on 2013-10-17**:
Indeed, I am running raring. I should have mentioned that, my apologies. I will try your suggestion.